# how can i use variables in selenium using tkinter

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

i am making an automation app, using tkinter as a frontend and selenium to automate, in this code below i want to get input from both the entry tags and feed the input in the  and ,how can i do that?, heres the code and i want to feed the input into the username_input.send_keys("")
password_input.send_keys("')

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
win=Tk()

def functionz():
    n=Entry1.get()
    m=Entry2.get()
    browser=webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    login_link= browser.find_element_by_xpath(" / /a[ text()= ' Log in ']" )
    login_link.click()
    sleep(2)
    username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")

    username_input.send_keys("<n>")
    password_input.send_keys("<m>")

    login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    login_button.click()

    sleep(5)

    browser.close()    

Canvas = Canvas(win, bg="#c2f0c2", height=250, width=1000)
Canvas.grid(row=0, column=4)

Labela=Label(Canvas, text="Enter username", font="verdana 23", bg="#8080ff")
Labela.grid(row=2, column=0)

Entry1=Entry(Canvas, font="verdana 23", bg="#ccccff")
Entry1.grid(row=2 , column=1)

Labelb=Label(Canvas, text="Enter Password", font="verdana 23", bg="#8080ff")
Labelb.grid(row=3, column=0)

Entry2=Entry(Canvas, font="verdana 23", bg="#ccccff")
Entry2.grid(row=3 , column=1)

button1=Button(Canvas, text="Send", font="Verdana 22" , command=functionz)
button1.grid(columnspan=4)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the error or problem your facing?

Comment: Dont pass `"<n>"` in `username_input.send_keys("<n>")` . Instead pass `n`

Comment: @CoolCloud its not feeding the inputs i have into the instagram login page

Comment: `'<n>'` should be `f'<{n}>'`, im not sure if this how you would send something onto selenium but ya